# Hyperledger fabric remove organisation from channel configuration results in error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Below is my use case:

I have two organisations Org1,Org2, when i replace Org2 from the channel configuration every thing works well, organisation gets removed from the channel, but when i remove the Org1 which is at index 0 in the config json and update it to the channel results in the  error listed below. It seems like i am able to remove organisations in LIFO (LAST IN FIRST OUT) manner but i want to achieve the functionality where i can remove an organisation irrespective of the order of addition.

```
error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': initializing policymanager failed: policy Admins at path Channel/Application did not compile: identity index out of range, requested 1, but identities length is 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not properly updating any policies that refer to the organization being removed.

When you remove an organization, you must remove the entire entry under `Application.groups`, for example `Application.groups.Org1MSP`.

You must also remove the organization from any policies under `Application.policies`, for example `Application.policies.Admins`.

Depending on the policy type, you may have one or more policies that look like this (`AND('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.admin')`):

```
"Admins": {
    "mod_policy": "Admins",
    "policy": {
        "type": 1,
        "value": {
            "identities": [
                {
                    "principal": {
                        "msp_identifier": "Org1MSP",
                        "role": "ADMIN"
                    },
                    "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                },
                {
                    "principal": {
                        "msp_identifier": "Org2MSP",
                        "role": "ADMIN"
                    },
                    "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                }
            ],
            "rule": {
                "n_out_of": {
                    "n": 1,
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "signed_by": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "signed_by": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "version": 0
        }
    },
    "version": "0"
}
```

It is not enough to remove the organization from the `policy.value.identities` array. The `signed_by` values in the `policy.value.rule.n_out_of.rules` array reference entries (by their array index) in the `policy.value.identities` array.

The error you have suggests that you have a policy somewhere with a `signed_by` value of `1`, but the corresponding `policy.value.identities` array for the policy only has a length of 1.